# InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type when runing my django script

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, sqlite, cursor

i have the following function

```
def get_id(entityName, text):  

"""Retrieve an entity's unique ID from the database, given its associated     text.
If the row is not already present, it is inserted.
The entity can either be a sentence or a word."""  

    tableName = entityName + 's'  
    columnName = entityName
    cursor.execute('SELECT rowid FROM ' + tableName + ' WHERE ' + columnName + ' = %s', (text,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row:
        return row[0]
    else:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' (' + columnName + ') VALUES (?)', (text,))
        return cursor.lastrowid
```

when ever this method get called it producing this error

```
 cursor.execute('SELECT rowid FROM ' + tableName + ' WHERE ' + columnName + ' = ?', (text,))
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

currently this error is producing when i am running this in django 
otherwise its working fine.
what can be the reason ?

Comment: Why are you writing raw SQL in Django?

Comment: is there any problem ?

Comment: using Raw sql should not be causing this error

Comment: What type is `text`?

Comment: its  an string @DanielRoseman

Comment: thanks a lot @DanielRoseman ! you were really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the type of my parameter 0 (text) was a `<type 'unicode'>` , and the column data-type in database was a `text type` 
so  the error

```
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

is obvious, as parameter 0 is not meeting the type of database column
i did'nt get this earlier ,as i was getting this from another source.
 But after getting it is not a text type i had to convert it in text type
something like `str(text)`
its working like a charm now